# How to deal with "Recursive router rebuild detected." exception error

Tags: routes, installation

I am frequently seeing module installation and uninstallation fail with the error

> Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Recursive router rebuild detected." at /path/to/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteBuilder.php line 121

It seems the underlying problem is that something goes wrong, and the way that the error is handled tries to get router information that is already being changed.

Is the fact that it's producing this fatal WSOD exception a core bug? Or is this one of those things where they will always pass responsibility to whatever is causing the original error? Is there a good way to diagnose these problems?

It leaves the modules half-installed, like with entity types registered but no schema. It's not great.

An example error:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

RuntimeException: Recursive router rebuild detected. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuilder->rebuild() (line 121 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteBuilder.php).
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Routing\RouteBuilder->rebuild() (Line: 67)
Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProviderLazyBuilder->getRouteProvider() (Line: 104)
Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProviderLazyBuilder->getRoutesByPattern() (Line: 115)
Drupal\devel\EntityTypeInfo->getPathParts() (Line: 100)
Drupal\devel\EntityTypeInfo->setEntityTypeLinkTemplate() (Line: 75)
Drupal\devel\EntityTypeInfo->entityTypeAlter() (Line: 94)
devel_entity_type_alter() (Line: 539)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->alter() (Line: 334)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->alterDefinitions() (Line: 127)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 175)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 22)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinition() (Line: 136)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition() (Line: 257)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getHandler() (Line: 196)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getStorage() (Line: 497)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase::loadMultiple() (Line: 19)
Drupal\ggroup\Routing\SubgroupRouteProvider->getRoutes()
call_user_func() (Line: 146)
Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuilder->rebuild() (Line: 83)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Routing\RouteBuilder->rebuild() (Line: 67)
Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProviderLazyBuilder->getRouteProvider() (Line: 104)
Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProviderLazyBuilder->getRoutesByPattern() (Line: 115)
Drupal\devel\EntityTypeInfo->getPathParts() (Line: 100)
Drupal\devel\EntityTypeInfo->setEntityTypeLinkTemplate() (Line: 75)
Drupal\devel\EntityTypeInfo->entityTypeAlter() (Line: 94)
devel_entity_type_alter() (Line: 539)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->alter() (Line: 334)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->alterDefinitions() (Line: 127)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 175)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 22)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinition() (Line: 136)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition() (Line: 257)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getHandler() (Line: 196)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getStorage() (Line: 247)
Drupal\views\EventSubscriber\ViewsEntitySchemaSubscriber->onEntityTypeDelete() (Line: 51)
Drupal\views\EventSubscriber\ViewsEntitySchemaSubscriber->onEntityTypeEvent()
call_user_func() (Line: 142)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch() (Line: 145)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeListener->onEntityTypeDelete() (Line: 167)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityDefinitionUpdateManager->uninstallEntityType() (Line: 490)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->uninstall() (Line: 91)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Extension\ModuleInstaller->uninstall() (Line: 174)
Drupal\system\Form\ModulesUninstallConfirmForm->submitForm()
call_user_func_array() (Line: 114)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->executeSubmitHandlers() (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->doSubmitForm() (Line: 592)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm() (Line: 320)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm() (Line: 73)
Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult()
call_user_func_array() (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 564)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext() (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext() (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 158)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() (Line: 80)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle() (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass() (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle() (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle() (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle() (Line: 708)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle() (Line: 19)
```

Comment: Can you post a full error message with a stack trace?

Comment: You can see from bugs like [#2351353](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2351353) and [#2930715](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2930715) that different problems cause the original error. Supposedly it was "fixed", I am just wondering how people usually handle it.

Comment: Looks like it's the devel module triggering the error (at least at this iteration) - can you uninstall that module or do you just end up in the same loop?

Comment: The two issues mentioned is one very early core bug from 2014 and one from a contrib module from 2017, both fixed. In your case the culprit is the devel module, though, `Drupal\devel\EntityTypeInfo->getPathParts` is calling a route rebuild twice. And this is caused by two different modules Ggroup and Views invoking by some unlucky coincidence the devels alter hook multiple times.

Comment: should RouteProviderLazyBuilder set its own rebuilding flag before it tries to do the rebuild?

Comment: ha, i uninstalled devel and now i get  Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "devel.admin_settings" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName() (line 206 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php).

Comment: The fact that the route builder is run through a lazy-built proxy class doesn't matter. I would get rid of Ggroup first. This module doesn't work with Devel, in my opinion. It tries to derive routes from entities for which the entity type info is not yet discovered and devel is hooking into the entity type discovery to do its own thing before the routes are built.

Comment: By any chance did you apply patch from issue [#2726209](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel/issues/2726209#comment-13573873) if yes, remove the patch and try again. It will most probably solve your issue.

Comment: Hmm. I had been using that patch but I removed it from composer in addition to adding some hacks to RouteProviderLazyBuilder. Too many changes at once. It does seem like removing that patch is sufficient in itself. I think Devel needs to add something there to prevent this.